# Map formats supported by QGIS

Tags: qgis, geotiff-tiff, file-formats, dted, s-57

May i know whether QGIS supports the following map formats?
(1) S-57 Electronic Navigation Charts (Naval Maps)
(2) Army/IAF Maps in DGN
(3) DTEDO0, DTEDO1 and DTEDO2
(4) GeoTIFF
(5) DTED

Comment: OGR the backend for Vector data in QGIS supports ENC-S57, but in won't show the specific symbology, just the data. DGN is sppported but not the newest version (no personal experience). I don't know about the military stuff, but i don't think so. Geotiff is supported fully.

Answer (score 7):

All the 'GDAL formats' (raster formats) are here http://www.gdal.org/formats_list.html.
(3) DTEDO0, DTEDO1 and DTEDO2 (4) GeoTIFF (5) DTED are the supported formats.

Comment: The exact details differ on the options that GDAL was compiled with though, many distros do not include everything.

Answer (score 4):

The `GDAL` section of the `Options` from the `Settings` menu will tell you which raster file formats GDAL in your QGIS can load.

[image: GDAL settings]

I can't find a corresponding list for OGR (vector) drivers, but the popup on the "Load Vector Layer" probably has all the file-based ones:

[image: vector file types]